# Accessing shared component element in DOM in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, dom

**Shared component:** pro-image

This component has image element with id proImg

```
<img id="proImg" src="{{imgPath}}">
```

imgPath is @input variable.

This component is used in multiple components and each parent passes image path and image dimension to above shared component.

In this shared component.ts file, I'm trying to access `<img>` element by id to add some attributes to the element. But while access element by Id only last element is getting accessed.

I want to uniquely this image element each time its been used in other component similar to host selector. Please suggest how can I achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that they all have the same `id` property.  `id` should be unique, per Mozilla docs for `getElementById` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

One option, instead of using the `id`, use a `ViewChild` to access the DOM Element.

Change your template to this

```html
<img #proImg [src]="imgPath">
```

And in your component you can access it this way:

```js
class MyCmponent {
@ViewChild('proImg', {static: true}) proImg: ElementRef;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        // you can access the native dom element like this:
        this.proImg.nativeElement.style.height = "100px";
        this.proImg.nativeElement.style.width = "100px";
    }
}
```

---

Another option, if you are just setting styles or other properties, you can bind them in the template

```html
<img [src]="imgPath" [ngStyle]="styles" [ngClass]="classes">
```

Component

```js
class MyComponent {

styles = { 
    width: "100px",
    height: "200px
}

classes = ['class1', 'another-class']
```

More on ngStyle https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle

More on ngClass https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass